# How to get the json files data in an alphabetic order

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json

I parsed three different json files using AngularJS. Here's my code:

Factory code

```
app.factory('myapp', ['$http', function($http) {        
    function getLists() {
        var tab = ['url1', 'url2', 'url3'];
        var list = [];
        for(i = 0; i < tab.length; i++) {
            $http.get(tab[i]) 
            .then(function(res) {
                list.push(res.data);
            });
        }
        return list;
    }

    return {
        getLists: getLists
    };
]);
```

What I want is to display the data of the different files in a  , the data of the first url in the first line , the second one in the second line  , etc... 
I have to display the data depending on the alphabetic order of the names 'nm'.

Html code:

```
<tr ng-repeat="d in list">
    <td>{{d.nm}}</td>
    <td>{{d.cty}}</td>   
    <td>{{d.hse}}</td>
    <td>{{d.yrs}}</td> 
</tr>
```

What should I do?

Comment: You may want to look into this popular question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can simply use orderBy

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy

like so

```
<tr ng-repeat="d in list | orderBy: 'nm'">
    <td>{{d.nm}}</td>
    <td>{{d.cty}}</td>   
    <td>{{d.hse}}</td>
    <td>{{d.yrs}}</td> 
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not explaining where you are getting the list from, so I'll assume one axiom and two options:

**Axiom**: You don't need to sort on-line (meaning, the user cannot trigger a different sort.

**Option 1** - You are getting the list from a DB: In this case, make sure that you add an index to each record and order the data by the index in ascending order.

**Option 2** - You are populating the list within the JavaScript code: in this case, you can build the list in order and with the addition of an index (I would suggest you make it numerical and not textual).